# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement.addItem

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu comecei a fazer o programa em JS para ter interação com o front e me apareceu esse erro. Quando é para mostrar o produto, ele funciona mostrando o nome do produto no console, mas bate esse erro, gostaria de saber como consertar

```
const select = document.querySelectorAll("[data-ordem]");
const shopProduct = [
 {
    num: 0,
    name: 'Bebedouro',
    price: 20
  },
  {
    num: 1,
    name: 'Massageador para gatos',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    num: 2,
    name:'Kit Spray com brinquedo de catnip',
    price: 40
  },
  {
    num: 3,
    name:'Sache de Catnip',
    price: 5
  }
];

select.forEach((e) => {
  let newItem = parseInt(e.dataset.ordem);
  e.addEventListener('click', addItem);
    function addItem(e){
      e.preventDefault();
        for(i=0; i <= shopProduct.length; i++){
          if(newItem === shopProduct[i].num){
            console.log(shopProduct[i].name);
          }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A propriedade `length` de um array devolve o seu tamanho. Porém, a sua indexação começa sempre na posição 0, o que significa que um array cujo `length` seja 3 tem os índices 0, 1 e 2.

Assim sendo, o erro acontece porque está a tentar aceder ao índice 4 de um array que tem os índices 0, 1, 2 e 3. A causa está na condição de paragem do ciclo `for`.

Experimente alterar:

```
for(i=0; i <= shopProduct.length; i++){
```

Para:

```
for(i=0; i < shopProduct.length; i++){
```

Comment: Eu não tinha pensado dessa forma sobre o for, me deu um jeito novo de pensar e ainda resolveu meu bug, muito obrigado.

Comment: Ótimo. Se a resposta foi útil, assinale-a como correta ;-)

Comment: Feito. Ainda estou aprendendo a usar a plataforma